# Insert on duplicate key update - insert won't post anything into db, update does

Tags: php, mysql

I've built a "master table" that fetches data from 4 tables. The purpose of this table is that users can place bets on football games - therefore I'm displaying all available matches plus the bets that are already available (but also the games where no bets are available yet). This "placing bets" function is built as `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

When I now try to insert a new bet (aka "Tipp" in the code below) it won't create a new database entry. On the other hand when I update an entry (which I have added directly via `phpMyAdmin`) via `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` everything works fine and existing entries in the table `tipps`get updated.

Any idea why `INSERT` won't work? Please let me know when you need to know more about the code.

**Master table**

```
<form method="POST" action="savebets.php">
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>time</th>
        <th>home</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>away</th>
        <th colspan="2">tipp</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"allerlei");
    $names = mysqli_query($conn,"set names utf8");
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, "
    //SQL query, see below
    ");    
    while($pers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $pers["id"] ?><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $pers["id"]?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["date"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["time"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["match_id"]?><input type="hidden" name="match_id[]" value="<?php echo $pers["match_id"]?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["home_name"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["goals_home"]?>
        </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["goals_away"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pers["away_name"]?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id[]" value="<?php echo $pers["user_id"]?>">
        <td><input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" name="tipp_home[]" value="<?php echo $pers["tipp_home"]?>"></td>
        <td><input type="tel" size="1"  maxlength="2" name="tipp_away[]" value="<?php echo $pers["tipp_away"]?>"></td>                            
        <input type="hidden" name="tipp_id[]" value="<?php echo $pers["tipp_id"]?>">
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="SUBMIT" name="submitbutton" value="Tipps speichern"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**action script (`savebets.php`)**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("connect.php");
$tipp_id = $_POST["tipp_id"];
$match_id = $_POST["match_id"];
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$goals_home = $_POST["tipp_home"];
$goals_away = $_POST["tipp_away"];
$failsCount = 0;
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    if(!$goals_home[$key] && !$goals_away[$key]) {
        continue;
    }
    $result="
            INSERT INTO tipps 
                (tipp_id, match_id, user_id, goals_home, goals_away)
            VALUES 
                ('$tipp_id', '$match_id[$key]', '$user_id[$key]', '$goals_home[$key]', '$goals_away[$key]')

            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                match_id = '".$match_id[$key]."',
                user_id = '".$user_id[$key]."',
                goals_home = '".$goals_home[$key]."',
                goals_away = '".$goals_away[$key]."'
            ";
            $query=mysqli_query($conn,$result);
            if(!$query) {
                $failsCount++;
            }
        } else {
            $notSavedCount++;
        }
     if($failsCount == 0 && $notSavedCount == 0) {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Succes! Deine Tipps wurden gespeichert.";
        header("Location:mastertable.php#bottom");
    } elseif($failsCount !=0) {
        echo "Fail, an error occured, try again.";
    } else {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Succes! Tipps gespeichert. <b>Hinweis</b>: Du hast noch offene Tipps! Bitte fülle alle Felder aus.";
        header("Location:mastertable.php#bottom");
    }
?>
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT
    matchschedule.id, 
    matchschedule.home, 
    matchschedule.away, 
    matchschedule.goals_home, 
    matchschedule.goals_away, 
    DATE_FORMAT(matchschedule.date, \"%d.%m.%Y\") AS date, 
    DATE_FORMAT(matchschedule.time, \"%H:%i\") AS time, 
    home.name AS home_name, 
    away.name AS away_name,
    tipps.goals_home AS tipp_home,
    tipps.goals_away AS tipp_away,
    tipps.punkte_tipp,
    tipps.tipp_id,
    tipps.match_id,
    login.user,
    login.id AS user_id
FROM matchschedule LEFT JOIN teams home 
    ON matchschedule.home=home.id
    LEFT JOIN teams away 
    ON matchschedule.away=away.id
    LEFT JOIN tipps 
    ON matchschedule.id = tipps.match_id
    LEFT Join login
    ON tipps.user_id = login.id
WHERE user = '".$_SESSION['username']."' OR tipp_id is NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand from the code, `tipp_id` is the key that decides whether the query will do an insert or update. If `tipp_id` exists in the database, the query will do an update, because it's a duplicate key.

Now, from PHP perspective - the `$_POST['tipp_id']` has only the `tipp_id`-s that are sent from the view, i.e the ones that exist in the database. So, when you do a foreach, you only go through all existing `tipp_id`-s and call the sql if the `tipp_id` already exists in the database. That means if it doesn't, it will never reach the sql query, so it will never do an insert. Your sql is good, the problem is that it's never reached unless it should do an update.

Instead of doing a loop by an item that is not always present, you should take an item you know will always exist (is not part of a left join). `match_id` for instance. That would change your foreach loop to

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    if(!$goals_home[$key] && !$goals_away[$key]) {
        continue;
    }
    //here goes the update logic, only if the fields are inserted
}
```

I believe that should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. I tried to completely switch the two variables - didn't resolve it either.

Comment: I've just seen that `match_id` IS part of a left join but `matchschedule.id` is not. So I added `id` to the table and created another variable for `savebets.php`. Now ALL bets get filled, but with an empty value for match_id and user_id, which is essential for showing the tipps (WHERE user = session-user...). Any idea how to resolve that issue?

Comment: I was just writing the same thing :). In that case you can go with either tipp_home or tipp_away in the loop. That would be the best way cause you will only get the ones which have the wanted data filled. If they're both optional, then you can add another hidden field which value you will set to matchschedule.id and use it for the iteration only. You'll just need to make sure to skip the ones that don't have a bet placed.

Comment: I already tried it with (matchschedule.)id - but that lead to empty values in match_id and user_id in the "tipps" table (however, the insert function is working now, but not 100% correctly). ould you please edit your post and show how to use the id field correctly? I might have done something wrong...

Comment: You just need that line of code that will skip the ones that are not inserted

Comment: Now I'm getting an error 500 :-(
I've updated the action script above to what I have right now. Can you please check if there is a mistake?

Comment: You're missing the hidden input with name 'id' in your code.

Comment: No that's included, I'll just update the Master table part as well. give me a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115565/discussion-between-mario-and-trajchevska).